# How to append the first and last with " double quotes for dw variable in Dataweave mule

Tags: mule, mule-component, dataweave, mule-el

```
%output application/json
%var EmpIds=flowVars.empIDMap.EmpIds
---
    payload map using(eNumber=$.EMPLOYEE) {
                content: EmpIds.eNumber,
}
```

If i add value within double quotes i am getting value for example **EmpIds."6"** for
Need to append the first and last with " double quotes to get the value from EmpIds based on eNumber.

empIDMap data is :: {EmpIds={6=2, 19=3, 21=4, 36=5, 168421=6, 167727=7, 167729=8, 161759=9, 162052=10, 157633=11}}

can you please help on this.

Comment: please can you provide an example of the input and the expected output data?

Comment: I've deleted MEL tag because it isn't Mule Expression Language. MEL is Autodesk Maya Expression Language.

Answer (score 0):

To get value as string try `eNumber= $.EMPLOYEE ++ ""`. This works fine.